# css: let table fill whole site

Tags: html, css

I have this test site that only has this in its body:

```
<div id="tableHolder">
  <table style="position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0; border: 1px solid">
    <tr> 
      <td> 
         <div id="image-canvas" style="width: 800px; height: 600px"></div> 
      </td> 
      <td valign="top"> 
         <div id="list" style="width:400px; overflow: auto; height: auto; max-height: 600px; resize: vertical;"></div> 
      </td> 
    </tr> 
  </table>
</div>
```

how can i make this fill the whole site instead of only 1200x600 px?
setting 100% alone didnt help.

Comment: Add "width: 100%;" to the table.

Comment: GabrielSNM, what about the height?

Comment: Add width: 100%; height: 100% to the styling and it works.

Comment: Yes, it's correct... add the "height: 100%" too.

Comment: sorry forgot to mention i tried to split it 80 20 % each. 80 for image 20 for list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question does not really let me know what your looking for, but this works:

https://jsfiddle.net/fj47s0ur/

Added height:100%; and width:100% to the TABLE element.

```
<div id="tableHolder">
  <table style="position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0; border: 1px solid;width:100%;height:100%">
    <tr> 
      <td> 
         <div id="image-canvas" style="width: 100%; height: 100%"></div> 
      </td> 
      <td valign="top"> 
         <div id="list" style="width:100%; overflow: auto; height: min-height; max-height: 100%; resize: vertical;"></div> 
      </td> 
    </tr> 
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: i try to get a split of 80% 20% vertically. sorry forgot to mention.

Answer (score 0):

As those guys said, add width and height to the TABLE style. Next is your code changed (I also changed the border to 5 and color red to make it more visible). I tried it in firefox, Chrome and IE :

```
<div id="tableHolder">
  <table style="height:100%;width:100%;position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0; border: 5px solid red">
    <tr> 
      <td> 
         <div id="image-canvas" style="width: 800px; height: 600px"></div> 
      </td> 
      <td valign="top"> 
         <div id="list" style="width:400px; overflow: auto; height: auto; max-height: 600px; resize: vertical;"></div> 
      </td> 
    </tr> 
  </table>
</div>
```

Important : if you change the div "tableHolder"' style, the table is going to look bad, that's why I changed the table style, not the div's. In order to prove it, I will post the code with the div style changes :

```
<div id="tableHolder" style="height:100%;width:100%;background:yellow;">
  <table style="position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0; border: 5px solid red">
    <tr> 
      <td> 
         <div id="image-canvas" style="width: 800px; height: 600px"></div> 
      </td> 
      <td valign="top"> 
         <div id="list" style="width:400px; overflow: auto; height: auto; max-height: 600px; resize: vertical;"></div> 
      </td> 
    </tr> 
  </table>
</div>
```

If you want to play safe, change both!